# No output when using File::Find module

Tags: perl, closures, subroutine

I would like to count the total number of files whose `modify_time` is between `$atime` and `$btime`. Here is part of my code, but it doesn't return anything. What is wrong?

```
sub mtime_between {
    my $mtime=0;
    my $counts=0;
    $mtime = (stat $File::Find::name)[9] if -f $File::Find::name;
    if ($mtime > $atime and $mtime < $btime) {
        return sub { print ++$counts,"$File::Find::name\n"};
    }
```

When i call the subroutine, I get nothing.

```
find(\&mtime_between,"/usr");
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you can do anything with the return value from the wanted subroutine in find. You need to DO something inside your wanted subroutine. Either add something to a global array, print something, delete something, whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be returning a function.

Check [File::Find documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html#DESCRIPTION).

> `find()` does a depth-first search over the given `@directories` in the order they are given. For each file or directory found, it calls the `&wanted` subroutine.

In the wanted function you should do the things you want to do directly. To return a function reference will not work and this is why you are having problems.

So you actually want something more like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{say};
use File::Find;
use Data::Dumper;

my ($atime, $btime) = (1461220840, 1561220844);

sub findFilesEditedBetweenTimestamps {
    my ($atime, $btime, $path) = @_;
    my $count = 0;
    my @files = ();

    my $mtime_between = sub {
        my $mtime = 0;
        $mtime = (stat $File::Find::name)[9] if -f $File::Find::name;
        if ($mtime > $atime and $mtime < $btime) {
            push @files, $File::Find::name;
            $count++;
        }
        return;
    };

    find ($mtime_between, $path);

    say "Found a total of $count files";
    say "Files:";
    print Dumper(@files);
}

findFilesEditedBetweenTimestamps($atime, $btime, "./");
```

I get:

```
Found a total of 2 files
Files:
$VAR1 = './test.txt';
$VAR2 = './test.pl';
```

Comment: thx,if i just want to get the total number of the files not for each file. how to do ?

Comment: Edited, you need a variable out of the callback for counting the total.

Answer (score 2):

As has been said, the value returned by the `wanted` subroutine is ignored. Returning a callback from a callback may be a step too far for some!

This may be of interest. I've used the [`File::stat`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::stat) module to make extraction of the modification time more readable, and [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece), so that `$atime` and `$btime` can be expressed in readable strings instead of epoch values

There's no need to write a separate subroutine for the `wanted` function unless you prefer -- you can just use an anonymous subroutine in the `find` call. And it's easiest to simply `return` from the `wanted` subroutine if the node isn't a file

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Find;
use File::stat;
use Time::Piece;

sub count_files_between_times {

    my ($from, $to, $path) = @_;
    my $count = 0;

    find(sub {
        my $st = stat($_) or die $!;
        return unless -f $st;
        my $mtime = $st->mtime;
        ++$count if $mtime >= $fromand $mtime <= $to;
    }, $path);

    print "Found a total of $count files\n";
}

my ($from, $to) = map {
    Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')->epoch;
} '2016-04-19T00:00:00', '2019-04-22T00:00:00';

count_files_between_times($from, $to, '/usr');
```

---

#### Update

Some people prefer the [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) module. Personally I dislike it intensely, and having looked at the source code I am very wary of it, but it certainly makes this process more concise

Note that `File::Find::Rule` is layered on top of `File::Find`, which does the heavy-lifting for it. So it is essentially a different way of writing the `wanted` subroutine

```
use File::Find::Rule ();

sub count_files_between_times {

    my ($from, $to, $path) = @_;

    my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->mtime(">= $from")->mtime("<= $to")->in($path);

    printf "Found a total of %d files\n", scalar @files;
}
```

or if you prefer you can add the restrictions one statement at a time

```
use File::Find::Rule ();

sub count_files_between_times {

    my ($from, $to, $path) = @_;

    my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new;
    $rule->file;
    $rule->mtime(">= $from");
    $rule->mtime("<= $to");
    my @files = $rule->in($path);

    printf "Found a total of %d files\n", scalar @files;
}
```

Both of these alternative subroutines produce identical results to that of the original above